# Couldn't enqueue task queue in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Am using the following code to enqueue a task in google app engine. But I couldn't able to enqueue it.

```
html = urllib2.urlopen("http://google.com").read()
message = mail.EmailMessage(sender = "New Scrapper <temp@gmail.com>",
                                subject = "Sent from google app Engine")
message.to = "my_email@gmail.com"
message.body = "Thanks for visiting our website"

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
                self.response.write("in home page")

class google(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
                self.response.write("In google  class")
                message.send()
class queue(webapp2.RequestHandler):
        def get(self):
                self.response.write("In queue class.")
                taskqueue.add(url='/google')
                self.redirect('/')

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/',MainPage),('/google',google),('/queue',queue)], debug = True)
```

Comment: if i goto '/google' my application sending me Email as I expected. But If I go to '/queue' it should enqueue the  '/google' task and has to send me a Email. But it is not happening. How to resolve this?

Comment: add log traces to track it down or use the cloud debugger